# Transaction undefined error when creating object store in indexedDB

Tags: indexeddb

I have some trouble with my code that I hope you can help me with. I've put my .open and all it's following code (unupgradeneede, onsuccess, onerror aso.) in a js file and then I call it from another js file. But it seems like the code for openingen the IndexedDB and creating object stores never executes. This is the code

```
window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB ||    window.msIndexedDB;

contosoData = {

    db: null,

    useDb: function (successCallback) {
        var request = window.indexedDB.open("ContosoData", 2);

        request.onsuccess = function (e) {
            contosoData.db = request.result;
            console.log('indexeddb.success');
            successCallback();
        };

        request.onupgradeneeded = function (e) {
            console.log('indexeddb.upgradeneeded');

            contosoData.db = e.target.result;
            if (contosoData.db.objectStoreNames.contains("bookingStore")) {
                contosoData.db.deleteObjectStore("bookingStore");
                var bookingStore = contosoData.db.createObjectStore("bookingsStore", { keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true });
                bookingStore.createIndex = ('title', 'title', { unique: false });
                bookingstore.createIndex = ('id', 'id', { unique: true });
            }

            else if (contosoData.db.objectStoreNames.contains("workerStore")) {
                contosoData.db.deleteObjectStore("workerStore");
                var workerStore = contosoData.db.createObjectStore("workerStore", { keyPath: "employeeNr" });
            }

            else if (contosoData.db.objectStoreNames.contains("customerStore")) {
                contosoData.db.deleteObjectStore("customerStore");
                var customerStore = contosoData.db.createObjectStore("customerStore", { keyPath: "orgNr" });
            }

            var machineStore = contosoData.db.objectStoreNames.contains("machineStore", { keyPath: "machineNr" });
            contosoData.db.deleteObjectStore("machineStore");
            var machineStore = contosoData.db.createObjectStore("machineStore");
        };

        request.onerror = function (e) {
            console.log('indexeddb.onerror: ' + e);
        };
        request.onblocked = function (e) {
            console.log('indexeddb.locked');
        };
    }
};

contosoData.useDb(function (db) {
    var transaction = contosoData.db.transaction(['bookingsStore'], 'readwrite');
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore('bookingsStore');
    console.log(objectStore.name);
});
```

and then, when i try to run it, I get an transaction undefined when I try to create a transaction in the other js-file... I've checked that my js-file with the function where I open the IndexedDB is linked in a correct way and order to the html-file. I've also put some breake points and it looks like the useDb code never execute. This is the code

```
function init() {

    contosoData.useDb();

    calendar.createCalendar();
}


calendar.createCalendar = function () {

    var transaction = contosoData.db.transaction(["bookingStore"], "readwrite");
    var bookingStore = transaction.objectStore("bookingStore");
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing? I searched for it and I tried to find a solution but without success so far...

Answer (score 0):

Will that be something like this

```
function init() {

    calendar.createCalendar();
}


calendar.createCalendar = function () {

    var transaction = contosoData.db.transaction(["bookingStore"], "readwrite");
    var bookingStore = transaction.objectStore("bookingStore");
}


contosoData.useDb(init);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :-)
I've already tried and it doesn't work unfortunately, or it doesn't solve my problem... I don't have any problems getting in to the contosoData.useDb but then it doesn't get anything back from when I called the.open... So the onsuccess, onupgradeneede (where all the objectStores are created) never executes and then of course I do get a undefined transaction... But can't figure out what goes wrong when I try to open the indexed DB

Answer (score 0):

I've already seen two issues in your code.

First, the database is always opened using version 2. If you already had a database of version 2, you will never trigger the onupgradeneeded event. You'll need to check that first (i.e. in Chrome, press Ctrl-Shift-I and inspect under Resources).

Second, the code uses this logic

```
if (contosoData.db.objectStoreNames.contains("bookingStore")) {
                contosoData.db.deleteObjectStore("bookingStore");
                var bookingStore = contosoData.db.createObjectStore("bookingsStore", { keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true });
                bookingStore.createIndex = ('title', 'title', { unique: false });
                bookingstore.createIndex = ('id', 'id', { unique: true });
            }
```

For an empty database, it for sure will not have any object store, therefore the if block is always evaluated as false. The object store will never be created since they are resided in an always-false if block.